# No matter what I try to download I get the same errors

Tags: downloads

Every time I try to download something it gives these errors.

```
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/lubuntu-desktop/ppa/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease 403  Forbidden [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]       
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/lubuntu-desktop/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
```

I am extremely new and everything that I have tried has not worked.

Comment: FYI:  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support; *flavors* had shorter lives. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to assess the security status of your actual install. Your question is still on-topic here, but consider how much security matters to you and the results of prior command. You're now using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with LXDE (*not Lubuntu*).

Comment: PPAs are 3rd party sources;. so all security checks are on you to validate before adding to your system. That is a *disabled* PPA or *personal package archive*.  When I [view it](https://launchpad.net/~lubuntu-desktop/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) I get told it's *disabled* (as I expected it would be; and what you should see), with my having options to delete the PPA; re-enable it & more (*due to my login*), but the DISABLED you would have seen should have told you **not** to add it to your system.

Comment: FYI:  Unless you're using a *i386* or 32-bit *x86* machine, I see no reason for using Lubuntu 18.04 LTS.  I'd check you went to an official site (there are *fake* & *fan* sites offering downloads of Lubuntu) as you'll note Lubuntu 20.04 LTS is the *oldest fully-supported* release available; and 18.04 was the last using LXDE which has no *supported upgrade* path... ie. it's the *end-of-the-road* which ended *full* support as already stated April 2021 (*3 years after release*).  It makes sense for *i386* as later *i386* releases weren't LTS thus had shorter supported lives, not 64-bit boxes.

Comment: Also FYI: If you hadn't worked it out, there was nothing in that PPA useful for any *supported* release of Lubuntu; and like a lot of *official* projects, once support ends the PPA or source is *dropped* or in this case *disabled* (*contents were dropped*).

Comment: To AU mods/close-dup voters:   Maybe a better *dup* or answer is required for this, given the error differs because of the *disabled* nature of that PPA.  Is is worth adding/writing an answer to that; or does a *dup* of that already exist?  I didn't exist & had jumped to the *not have a release file* duplicate super early..  My checking the *disabled* status was just to validate it was *disabled* (ie. Lubuntu hat on) which wasn't support thinking...

Comment: I VTC as the duplicate you marked. Really though, this question contains a dearth of information and the only details that were provided are incomplete and unclear. OP, I think the duplicate will answer your problem, however if it doesn't, you should edit your question and include more clear details and context. Start by telling us what version of Ubuntu you're using. Describe all steps needed to reproduce the problem. And if you have problematic messages in the terminal, tell us the commands you are using and post the whole output - not just the parts you think are relevant.

Comment: "Everything I download" is incredibly ambiguous, but it does seem you're talking about installing software in apt. In that case show us `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` with any other commands you've used. Also, when you tell us you "tried everything", this can be incredibly exasperating for people trying to help, because that statement conveys no actual details. Specific and clear details about what you tried and the results of those attempts may help illuminate a path forward. When relaying details, try to be as clear and specific as possible.